# Cannot type U+037E

Tags: google-chrome, unicode

When I try to type U+037E on Google Chrome by using the <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> `NNNN` method (hold <kbd>ALT</kbd>, press <kbd>+</kbd> on numeric keypad, and then type the unicode on the number pad) I cannot since <kbd>ALT+E</kbd> is keybound to opening the Settings menu. Right now I'm entering `037` on the numeric keypad then pressing the letter <kbd>E</kbd> on the keyboard. Is there any way for me to type `U+037E` without disabling any keybindings or downloading any software?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i change my numpad from ASCII to Unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758279/how-do-i-change-my-numpad-from-ascii-to-unicode)

Comment: Read [Full description of Windows Alt+N codes](http://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602). `Alt`+`NNNN` requires `NNNN`  to be a decimal number. Another method (write hexadecimal, then `Alt`+`x` where `x` is _literally_ `x` letter works e.g. in _Sticky Notes_) does not work in my Google Chrome browser.

Comment: Duplicate of [Full Unicode keypad entry in Chrome (including E/F digits?)](http://superuser.com/questions/974496/full-unicode-keypad-entry-in-chrome-including-e-f-digits) on Superuser.

Comment: @一二三 Not sure if I made the right registry edit then. I added a key `EnableHexNumpad` in `HKCU/Control Panel/Input Method`. Its name is (Default), type is `REG_SZ`, and data is 1.

Comment: @JosefZ Sadly, `ALT+X` doesn't work for me in Sticky Notes, although it does work in Word. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: It's value not key. `reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method" /V EnableHexNumpad` should return `EnableHexNumpad    REG_SZ    1`

Comment: See [my answer on `Alt`+`+d`, `Alt`+`+e` and `Alt`+`+f`](http://superuser.com/a/1140571/376602).

Comment: If you have the Tampermonkey add-on installed in Chrome you can use [this userscript](https://github.com/calraith/gm_scripts/blob/master/Alt+Num_Extended_Char_Entry.user.js) to convert `U+037E` to `;` by typing `37E` and hitting Alt+X (like in MS Word).  [Full details](https://superuser.com/a/1216294/204705).